# PHP curl returning blank page

Tags: php, curl

Can anyone show me how to compose this request using curl php? I need to scrape a website, but the code I use (given below) always returns a blank page. 
I want to send

```
Accept-Encoding, Useragent, and cookie
```

Request:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.99 Safari/535.1

Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

to

https://example.com/

Thanks!

The code I tried to use (returned a blank page):

```
<?
$url='https://example.com';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
$request_headers = array();
$request_headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip';
$request_headers[] = 'Client: Apple';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'insertedmycookiehere');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.99 Safari/535.1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $curl_scraped_page;
?>
```

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: A couple of errors. 1. use <?php not <?. Line 3 is causing an error - comment it out and see if that works.

Comment: I'm noticing that the https version of example.com is giving me an error when I navigate there in my browser. Have you tried just trying http?

Comment: @jeff I fixed both the errors you noted, same thing happens. Also there is more than one header, I have included it in the main question.

Comment: @WoogieNoogie the 'https://example.com' is just an example :D but I did try http with my url.

Comment: You can't specify `$request_headers` after you've attempted to call them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me :

```
$url='http://example.com'; /* You incorrectly used https for this website */ 

$ch = curl_init($url);

$request_headers = array();
$request_headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip';
$request_headers[] = 'Client: Apple';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers); /* Moved this line here */

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'insertedmycookiehere');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.99 Safari/535.1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $curl_scraped_page;
```